# object being returned instead of function

Tags: javascript

Im trying to build a math quiz in JavaScript that is timed and gives 20 random generated math questions. However when start is pressed and the timer starts instead of the questions being outputed i'm getting [object, Object]. So my question is how to change this so it .eturns the randomly generated questions?

Here is my JS below:

```
window.onload = function () {

    var seconds = 00; 
    var tens = 00; 
    var appendTens = document.getElementById("tens");
    var appendSeconds = document.getElementById("seconds");
    var buttonStart = document.getElementById('button-start');
    var Interval ;

    buttonStart.onclick = function() {

      function generateQuestions () {

        let randNum1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
        let randNum2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;

        var op = ["*", "+", "/", "-"][Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)];
        return {number1: randNum1, operator: op, number2: randNum2};

    }

    var problemList = [];
    while (problemList.length < 20) {
        problemList.push(generateQuestions());

        document.getElementById("questions").innerHTML = problemList[0];

    }

       clearInterval(Interval);
       Interval = setInterval(startTimer, 10);



    }


    function startTimer () {
      tens++; 

      if(tens < 9){
        appendTens.innerHTML = "0" + tens;
      }

      if (tens > 9){
        appendTens.innerHTML = tens;

      } 

      if (tens > 99) {
        console.log("seconds");
        seconds++;
        appendSeconds.innerHTML = "0" + seconds;
        tens = 0;
        appendTens.innerHTML = "0" + 0;
      }

      if (seconds > 9){
        appendSeconds.innerHTML = seconds;
      }

    }

  }
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("questions").innerHTML = problemList[0];` should be `document.getElementById("questions").innerHTML = \`${problemList[0].number1} ${problemList[0].operator} ${problemList[0].number2};\``

Answer (score 0):

You return object with this line.

```
return {number1: randNum1, operator: op, number2: randNum2};
```

If you want to return string as question you can type:

```
return randNum1.toString() + op + number2.toString();
```

And this part should be also fixed:

```
while (problemList.length < 20) {
    problemList.push(generateQuestions());

    document.getElementById("questions").innerHTML = problemList[0];

}
```

You need to display each time new question. Not all the time the same one.

```
for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    problemList.push(generateQuestions());

    document.getElementById("questions").innerHTML = problemList[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I made you a simple example

```js
var questionsElement = document.querySelector("#questions");

function randInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}

function randQuestions(len) {
  var questions = [];
  while(questions.length < len) {
    questions.push({number1: randInt(100), operator: ["+","*","-","/"][randInt(4)], number2: randInt(100)});
  }
  return questions;
}

var problemList = randQuestions(20);
for(var i = 0;i < problemList.length; i++) {
  questionsElement.innerHTML += `<li>${problemList[i].number1} ${problemList[i].operator} ${problemList[i].number2} = ?</li>`;
}
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  font: bold 20px monospace; 
}
```

```html
<ul id="questions"></ul>
```